# CouchDB view works only when not saved

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm having a very weird error when using a CouchBD view: it works only when not saved, and with that I mean that if I add an empty line it will work correctly, but if I click the Save button in the Futon interface it will abruptly quit (instantly) with a

```
Error: os_process_error
{exit_status,1}
```

The view itself is quite simple, and I can't really grasp what might be wrong about it..

```
def startEmitter(doc):
  if 'start_' in doc:
    yield("start", { 'min': doc['start_'], 'max': doc['start_'] })
```

The reducer:

```
def minmaxStartReducer(keys, values, rereduce):
  min = values[0]['min']
  max = values[0]['max']

  for val in values:
    if val['max'] > max:
      max = val['max']
    if val['min'] < min:
      min = val['min']
  return {'max':max,'min':min}
```

Comment: Does the view work if you write it in JavaScript (as you're using an extension to get python to work).

Comment: Yes, it does, but I think that's beyond the scope of the question; I'm baffled by how it doesn't matter where I put the blank line, if within the emitter or the reducer, the thing works only as long as it's temporary, and I can't begin to imagine why.

Comment: I would suggest that you create an issue here-http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/issues/list, And, post your question on their group: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=en#!forum/couchdb-python

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the reason in the log: http://yourserver.com:5984/_log

Comment: I don't think the log facilities are being useful for this instance, as they only report `[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 08:26:37 GMT] [error] [<0.575.0>] OS Process Error <0.583.0> :: {os_process_error,
                                                   {exit_status,1}}
[Thu, 08 Aug 2013 08:26:37 GMT] [error] [emulator] Error in process <0.575.0> with exit value: {{nocatch,{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}},` over and over..

Comment: Very strange. Usually there is a stacktrace. I was always find reasons in the stacktrace in the most mysterious situations. Try to get longer log http://yourserver.com:5984/_log?bytes=1048576

Comment: Ok I increased my logging level, now it looks like the view executing is a completely different one (that crashes, but that's clearly another issue) :-/

Comment: You've got closer, now you can make this question answered :)

Comment: Why would I do that? I still see no reason as to why another random view should be executed.. It's an interesting step forward, but the original question still stands whole.